# Loading resources in a maven project with exec-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, classpath

Having two issues here. I have a Maven project, with pom.xml specifying resources as

```
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/sql</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
```

And then I have an exec-maven-plugin section such as

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>RunMyTest</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>java</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>com.foo.RunMyTest</mainClass>
          <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
          <addResourcesToClassPath>true</addResourcesToClassPath>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

(Here, `com/foo/RunMyTest.java` lives in `src/test/java`).

Now, I have two issues. First, somewhat minor: if I run this with

`mvn -X exec:java@RunMyTest`

I see in the output `[DEBUG]   (f) addResourcesToClasspath = false`. Does `<addResourcesToClassPath>true</addResourcesToClassPath>` not have any effect?

But that can be for now overridden with running

```
mvn  exec:java@RunMyTest -DaddResourcesToClasspath=true
```

Now I see `[DEBUG]   (f) addResourcesToClasspath = true`. BUT! The problem is, in my code I call code from a dependency, which in turn uses  `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("foo.txt");` where `foo.txt` is under `src/main/sql` -- and this returns `null`. Testing in my code by doing `RunMyTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource("foo.txt")`, however, works. It appears that the system classloader does not see the resources path. Is there any nice way around it?

Comment: addResourcesToClasspath may be case sensitive?

Comment: Ah good catch. Thank you. Should have been `<addResourcesToClasspath>true</addResourcesToClasspath>`. So that takes care of the first part of the question -- this now works without `-DaddResourcesToClasspath=true`.

But the classloader problem still stands.

Comment: @GregoryGolberg did you ever manage to solve the problem with getResources()?  I have the same issue when using exec-maven-plugin, and hours of googling so far has got me nowhere ...